# how to save Save the output of the command, "npm run migrations" to a variable

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, circleci

I want to grep for the text, "has been executed successfully" in the output to ensure the migration was successful before running the next jobs.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I think this will work, SUCCESS=$(npm run migrations)
 if (( $SUCCESS == 0 ));
            then
            echo success
 fi

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `command1 || command2`  means run command2 if command1 fails, so you could do `npm run migrations || exit 1` which will exit the program if `npm run migrations` fails. then use `$wait` in the next line to wait for completion.

Comment: Thanks Aviv Keller